# multicolumn unique key mysql insert

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a mysql database, and a table structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_session_log` (
 `stat_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `metric` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `platform` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `page_id` varchar(128) DEFAULT '_empty_',
 `target_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `country` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ISO 3166 country code (2 symbols)',
 `amount` int(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000' COMMENT 'counter or amount',
 `unique_key` varchar(180) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Optional unique identifier',
 `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`stat_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `unique_key` (`unique_key`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `target_date` (`target_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21657473 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to log the active sessions / unique users based on date, and page_id, and country. Currently I'm able to achieve this by generating multiple insert statements with unique_key, buy adding a page_id and date in the unique key but I want something a little bit different. 
The logic should be: insert new row of unique_key (semi-unique user id), where country = this, date = this, page_id = this. If there is already a row with such information (same page_id, unique_key, and date + country) - update the amount = (amount) + 1; (session).
So I could do lookups like :

`SELECT sum(amount) WHERE page_id = "something" AND target_date = "2018-12-21"`

This would give me a number of sessions. OR:

`SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE page_id = "something" AND target_date = "2018-12-21"`

This would give me a number of active users on that pagee_id on that day
OR:

`SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE target_date = "2018-12-21"`

Which would give me a result of total users on that day. 
I know about unique index, but would it give me a result I'm looking for?

---

Edit, a sample insert:
`` INSERT INTO `user_session_log` (`platform`,`page_id`,`target_date`,`country`,`amount`,`unique_key`,`created`,`modified`) VALUES ('1','page_id_54','2018-10-08','US',1,'ea3d0ce0406a838d9fd31df2e2ec8085',NOW(),NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `amount` = (amount) +1, `modified` = NOW(); ``
and the table should know if theres a duplicate based on if theres a same unique_key + date + country + platform + page_id, otherwise just insert a new row. 
Right now I'm doing this differently by having different metrics and a unique_key generated already containing the date + page_id and then hashed. that way it's unique by means i can filter the different unique users on a day basis, but I can't filter the amount of sessions that unique user has had, or how long he uses  the software and similar.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample .. and the expected  result

Comment: added an example insert.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL 'UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY' without a unique column?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3180913/90527)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly create unique index on all the columns that needs to be unique as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE user_session_log ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_multi_column  ON user_session_log (unique_key, date, country, platform, page_id);
```

then you can use  [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) query to insert/update.

Comment: well I'm doing this already, the difference is that I want to have a duplicate key based on multiple columns.

Comment: composite key of all the columns that need to be unique might help...i guess

Comment: does index of multiple columns work the same as a singular unique key?

Comment: A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index must be distinct which is what you need  as i understand. [refer here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-unique). I hope this helps...